# alternative to for(var x in array)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an two arrays of products called cart and stock. 
Let's say there are 5 products a to e.

Stock might look like

```
stock[a] = 5, stock[b] = 5...
```

etc etc

and cart might look like

```
cart[a] = 2, cart[b] = 0...
```

I am trying to do something like

`for (var product in cart){
    if(cart[product] > 0){
    cart[product] = stock[product]
}`

But stock[product] always returns 0. How can i make it so that I can use the same variable product to access products within both stock and cart?

I tried something like

```
for (var product in cart && var product in stock)
```

but it doesnt work.

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: ”But stock[product] always returns 0” – how are you determining this?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? You already can use `product` as a key in both `stock` and `cart`, so you must have another problem. Have you tried `console.log` on `stock` and `cart` to see if they contain what you think they do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: Instead of reusing your question and changing it to another one, you should just make a new question, it works out better for you because people tend to look at the newest questions. But above all this question is now completely confusing, nothing matches between the comments/answers and your question.

Comment: Uh, just don't make synchronous XMLHTTPRequests? They *do freeze* the browser, that's exactly why you shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear as to whether or not you are iterating over an array or an object, but since your question says array, I will assume both `cart` and `stock` are arrays and `a` and `b` are numbers.

As Chris L mentioned, you probably shouldn't be using a `for..in` loop for arrays, so I would recommend just a normal `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
  if (cart[i] > 0) {
    cart[i] = stock[i];
  }
}
```

If you target IE9+, a `forEach` is a little cleaner, in my opinion.

```
cart.forEach(function (item, index) {
  if (item > 0) {
    cart[index] = stock[index];
  }
}
```

Side note: this code looks like it's re-assigning `cart[i]` if it's greater than 0 which seems very weird to me...